# Does the Plasma Membrane have a hydrophilic interior/exterior/contain vesicles?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, cell-membrane, structural-biology

I am very new to the study of biology, and have been unable to find information in other sources which could tell me whether the **plasma membrane** has the following traits:

- has a hydrophilic interior
- has a hydrophobic exterior
- contains vesicles

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you look for sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plasma membrane is a lipid bilayer. Plasma membrane lipids have a hydrophilic head group and hydrophobic tail groups. Since cells are usually in an aqueous environment (and are filled with aqueous cytoplasm), the hydrophilic head groups is face both the exterior and interior of the cell. Between these head groups facing the interior and exterior, the hydrophobic tail groups of opposing lipids associate with each other to create a hydrophobic core within the membrane.

Vesicles are also made of lipid bilayers. Vesicles can exist within cells or be released by cells.

Comment: Please add some references to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The plasma membrane typically refers to the double lipid bilayer, which has a hydrophillic exterior and a hydrophobic interior.  In your case, the only thing I can think of is a layer/mixture of inverted micelles, which would fulfill your three criterion.
[image: Notice figure e]

Image is from "Lecithin-based nanostructured gels for skin delivery: An update on state of art and recent applications"

Comment: Please add some references to your answer.